# jQuery: how to get the whole entire tag-element which was found with a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If a am searching for an element, ie. an option in a select box, how to get the whole entire option tag as html?

```
<select name="xy">
  <option id="xyz" value="abc">something here</option>
  some more options
</select>
```

this is not what i want to get:

```
$('select[name="xy"] option[value="abc"]').html()
```

this only returns me

```
"something here"
```

but i want to get the whole tag

```
<option id="xyz" value="abc">something here</option>
```

in foreach function this does work pretty fine

```
$('option[value="abc"]').each(function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

returns me my searched

```
<option id="xyz" value="abc">something here</option>
```

but a foreach there must not be neccesary, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that exact `string` from some reason, then you can follow Andrei's answer. Just keep in mind that it will be a `string` object and not a `DOM` object. If you want to use the actual object still, you can just use `$('select[name="xy"] option[value="abc"]')[0]` and this will return the `DOM` element at the 0 index of the jQuery selector. If you want this entire string to add elements elsewhere in the page, this is a roundabout way of doing that. You can still use jQuery for this without going into native javascript. For example:

```
var $copy_this = $('select[name="xy"] option[value="abc"]');
$('.some_other_place').append($copy_this.clone());
```

Now, the `div` with class 'some_other_place' will have an exact copy of that `option` element.

Comment: really? oh! Thats nice! I just want to delete some items if needed and put them again in if some events were happen. Looks like, this is a better way to do so.

Comment: @Viktor Sry, I forgot to add the `clone` method. This is a good methodology to use because it caches the jQuery and allows you to reuse it again without recalculating. Then you can just `$variable_name.clone()` anywhere you want to.

Comment: @Viktor Perhaps not in this example, but if you do not use `clone()` then it will actually remove the element from where it is an append it somewhere else. Cloning the element will clone it, lol, instead of just 'cut and pasting' it.

Comment: should it not be the way round? var $copy_this = $('select[name="xy"] option[value="abc"]').clone();
$('.some_other_place').append($copy_this);

Comment: i do need much of those copies and as i do understand .clone(), it's much more performant without .clone()  _"For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements without .clone()"_

Comment: @Viktor If you do it like that, every time you reference `$copy_this` you will be referencing the cloned element, you will not be 're-cloning' the first element. You can see this effect here to better understand it: http://jsfiddle.net/NKLuB/ Since I have appended the test div twice, it should appear in both divs. But, alas, that is not how it works.

Comment: _"you will be referencing the cloned element, you will not be 're-cloning' the first element."_ This is exactly what i need ;) otherwise i would create about 10 clones for one object

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use native `outerHTML` property of the DOM element:

```
$('select[name="xy"] option[value="abc"]')[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: @Viktor, jQuery gives you a list of objects matching a selector. Even if there is one such object, `$()` will give a list, and list does not know about `outerHTML`. So `[0]` is to access first element of that list